# Entering multiple SPI interfaces

Tags: c++, arduino

I am having a problem with my code for arduino m0 (using microchip SAMD21). There are two SPI interfaces, first classic and second with int variable in front of the pin name, int MISO, for instance. Does someone know, how to control this classic SPI interface?

I have also attached my code.

PS: Code stucks in begin function of OZONE2CLICK sensor...

```
#include "Arduino.h"

#include <MQ131.h>

             // include RFM69 library
#include <SPI.h>

// Local
#define PC_BAUDRATE         56700
#define MS_DELAY        0  // Number of milliseconds between data sending and LED signalization
#define LED_DELAY       100
#define Serial SerialUSB

// SD card
#define sd_cs_pin 35 // set SD's chip select pin (according to the circuit)

  float PPMO2;
  float PPBO2;
  float MGM3O2;
  float UGM3O2;

  const byte pinSS = 2; //cs pin
  const byte pinRDY = 12;
  const byte pinSCK = 13;
  const byte O2Pin = 10;
  #define DcPin 8

// SD card file
File file; // SD library variable

// LEDS
#define D13_led_pin 42  // D13 LED
#define M_led_pin 36    // MLED

// Local variables
int idCounter = 1;
bool isBmeOk = true;
bool isSdOk = true;
bool isRadioOk = true;
bool isGpsConnected = true;

  void OZONE2CLICKCalibrate ()
  {
  Serial.println("2");
    //MQ131.begin(pinSS, pinRDY, O2Pin, LOW_CONCENTRATION, 10000);  //(int _pinCS, int _pinRDY, int _pinPower, MQ131Model _model, int _RL)
    Serial.println("99");
    Serial.println("Calibration in progress...");

    MQ131.calibrate();

    Serial.println("Calibration done!");
    Serial.print("R0 = ");
    Serial.print(MQ131.getR0());
    Serial.println(" Ohms");
    Serial.print("Time to heat = ");
    Serial.print(MQ131.getTimeToRead());
    Serial.println(" s");
    }

  void OZONE2CLICKMeasure ()
  {
    Serial.println("Sampling...");
    MQ131.sample();
    Serial.print("Concentration O3 : ");
    PPMO2 = MQ131.getO3(PPM);
    Serial.print(PPMO2);
    Serial.println(" ppm");
    Serial.print("Concentration O3 : ");
    PPBO2 = MQ131.getO3(PPB);
    Serial.print(PPBO2);
    Serial.println(" ppb");
    Serial.print("Concentration O3 : ");
    MGM3O2 = MQ131.getO3(MG_M3);
    Serial.print(MGM3O2);
    Serial.println(" mg/m3");
    Serial.print("Concentration O3 : ");
    UGM3O2 = MQ131.getO3(UG_M3);
    Serial.print(UGM3O2);
    Serial.println(" ug/m3");
  }

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(PC_BAUDRATE);

  // wait for the Arduino serial (on your PC) to connect
  // please, open the Arduino serial console (right top corner)
  // note that the port may change after uploading the sketch
  // COMMENT OUT FOR USAGE WITHOUT A PC!
  // while(!Serial);

  Serial.println("openCanSat PRO");

  Serial.print("Node ");
  Serial.print(MYNODEID,DEC);
  Serial.println(" ready");

  // begin communication with the BME280 on the previously specified address
  // print an error to the serial in case the sensor is not found
  if (!bme.begin(BME280_ADDRESS_OPEN_CANSAT))
  {
      isBmeOk = false;
      Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor, check wiring!");
      return;
  }

  // begin communication with the INA219
  ina219.begin();

  // check of Gps is connected
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x42); // 42 is addres of GPS
  int error = Wire.endTransmission();

  if (error != 0)
  {
      isGpsConnected = false;
  }

  // begin communication with gps
  gps.begin();

  // Uncomment when you want to see debug prints from GPS library
  // gps.debugPrintOn(57600);

  if(!radio.initialize(FREQUENCY, MYNODEID, NETWORKID))
  {
      isRadioOk = false;
      Serial.println("RFM69HW initialization failed!");
  }
  else
  {
    radio.setFrequency(FREQUENCYSPECIFIC);
      radio.setHighPower(true); // Always use this for RFM69HW
  }

  pinMode(D13_led_pin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  pinMode(SS, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  pinMode(DcPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(O2Pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(DcPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(O2Pin, HIGH);
  delay(10000);
  OZONE2CLICKCalibrate();
  OZONE2CLICKMeasure();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It looks the code opening the SPI connection is commented out:

```
MQ131.begin(pinSS, pinRDY, O2Pin, LOW_CONCENTRATION, 10000);
```

**You need to configure the SPI connection to get any data from your device.**

Refer to reference code from the manufacturer or library you're using to make sure your programming against it correctly.

2. Please format your code with predictable spacing. This is pretty hard to read.
3. Since you're using C++, prefer to use:

```
constexpr <type> NAME = <value>;
```

rather than macros:

```
#define NAME (<value>)
```

4. Since this is a bare metal compilation, using `return` in the `setup()` or `loop()` functions does not *stop* them. You probably want something more like `while (true) {}`. This will loop the code indefinitely, rather than proceed in a bad state.

i.e.:

```
void stop_forever() {
  Serial.println("fatal error detected, stoping forever.");
  while (true) {}
}

// then, use it later:
// ...
if (error) {
  stop_forever();
}
// ...
```